# cloudfoundry java buildpack memory changes not reflecting

Tags: java, cloud-foundry, buildpack

I want to make changes in memory settings for my java apps in cloudfoundry java-buildpack. I have tried these two ways:

1. Using JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE paramter in my manifest.yml. As
   suggested in
   https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack-memory-calculator
2. Making this change in config\open_jdk_jre.yml:

> memory_calculator:
>   version: 3.8.0_RELEASE
>   repository_root:
>   "{default.repository.root}/memory-calculator/{platform}/{architecture}"
>   stack_threads: 300
>    memory_sizes:
>   stack: 2M
>   metaspace: 160M
>   heap: 900M

However, none of this is getting reflected while deployment of my apps. I am using latest java-buildpack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the version of the Java build pack that you're using.

#### Version 3.x

For versions 3.x, you would set an env variable to configure the memory calculator.  Like here.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/tree/3.x#configuration-and-extension

Ex:

```
cf set-env my-application JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE '{ memory_calculator: { memory_heuristics: { heap: 85, stack: 10 } } }'
```

This will then override the memory heuristics configuration that defaults in the build pack, specifically the heap and stack weights.

A few notes:

- Understanding what the different memory configuration options do is another matter.  You can read about those [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/3.x/docs/jre-open_jdk_jre.md#configuration).
- This is only for OpenJDK, if you're using a different JDK then the configuration options are slightly different. Ex: `JBP_CONFIG_ORACLE_JRE` for Oracle.  The name mirrors the [config file path & name](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/3.x/config/oracle_jre.yml).
- It doesn't matter how you set the env variable for your app.  You can use `cf set-env` like above or you can set the env variable in your manifest.yml file.  Both work just fine.

#### Version 4.x

In version 4.x, the configuration of the JVM's memory settings has gotten a lot simpler.

> however if you believe that your application doesn’t need these JVM defaults, you can now configure those memory regions directly with JVM options.

https://www.cloudfoundry.org/just-released-java-buildpack-4-0/

What this means is you still configure the JVM settings through an env variable, but you only need to set `JAVA_OPTS` and you use the standard JVM configuration options.

For example:

```
cf set-env my-app JAVA_OPTS '-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=100M'
```

You can set `JAVA_OPTS` in your manifest.yml, if you prefer doing that instead of running `cf set-env`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue - the setting for stackThreads was being ignored.  I was unclear about

- whether JavaBuildPack-4 supported a configuration like
  '{memory_calculator: {stack_threads: 202 } }'
- whether it was only supported in JBP-3 and JBP-4 didn't have an option to configure threads
- whether, as advised by
  https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/java-tips.html and
  https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/issues/416 to use
  right angle brackets JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE: '[memory_calculator:
  {memory_sizes: {native: 150m}}]'
- whether to use single quotes as advised [here](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/tree/v4.17.2) when only double quotes were accepted on the command line cf set-env ...

I eventually downloaded the [source code for JBP-4](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/tree/v4.17.2) and saw that it does indeed still support JBP_CONFIG_OPEN_JDK_JRE (just not all the memory settings that were supposed in JBP-3).  Daniel Mikusa supplied the most valuable tip in [44396432](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44396432/cloudfoundry-java-buildpack-memory-changes-not-reflecting?rq=1)
... when using an Oracle JRE, use JBP_CONFIG_ORACLE_JRE.
And of all the permutations of ",',[,{ this is what worked;

```
cf set-env APP_NAME JBP_CONFIG_ORACLE_JRE "{memory_calculator: {stack_threads: 202 } }"
```

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_OPTS not reflecting after adding Manifest file --
env:
JAVA_OPTS: "'-Xss1M'"

tried all types of syntax --
JAVA_OPTS: '-Xss1M'

The memory values in app Logs comes without -Xss value as shown below
JVM Memory Configuration: -Xmx343421K -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=193154K

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35201669)